# How to CTRL+S via VBA in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

MS Access: `CTRL+S` will save the currently open database file.
We can access it through `File > Save` menu too.

How can this be done via VBA?

I have tried `DoCmd.RunCommand(20)` but it only tries to save recordsets.

Comment: What do you mean with *saving database file*? Access will prompt a message to save changes **only** if you make any **design** changes to any object (queries, tables, forms, reports, modules). If you just open an Access file to add/modify/delete data (records), those changes are instantly saved. You don't need to *save the Access Database file* if you just added/edited/deleted records. You need to save only when you make changes in the design of the own database (new fields in a table, changing controls in a form, new codes on a module, editin the SQL code of a query, and so on).

Comment: `DoCmd.RunCommand(20)`, is the same as a click on File->Save, but that doesn't save vba-modules! This has to be done by click File->Save in VBA-IDE. Usullay there is no need to automate this by vba, because this is done only during development. You have to explain your reasons for that!

Answer (score 1):

In existing DB CTRL + S saves currently opened object. If it is a form this can be done like that

```vb
DoCmd.Save acForm, "MyForm"
```

More examples in manual: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.save

Comment: how can i save my open Access Database File?

Comment: DB consist of many objects (forms, queries etc). If you have no open objects there is nothing to save.